# Why I am facing an Origin error despite having included the header in the code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, mern

I am working on a website(MERN) which has a newsletter as well as a contact form both of my forms are sent on different routes, '/subscribe' and '/contact' respectively. I have hosted the server and client side on different domains. The contact form is working perfectly but in subscribe form I am facing a CORS error which says request denied by the server.

The specific error is "official-site-version-2-0-8tjp.vercel.app/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://official-site-version-2-0.vercel.app/subscribe' from origin 'https://official-site-version-2-0-8tjp.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

My server side code is

```
// Allow requests from your frontend domain
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ["https://official-site-version-2-0-8tjp.vercel.app","https://official-site-version-2-0.vercel.app"],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};


app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));
console.log(process.env.EMAIL_USER);
console.log(process.env.EMAIL_PASS);

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: <email>,
    pass: <password>
  },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

// Endpoint handler for handling contact form submissions
app.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.firstName + req.body.lastName;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const message = req.body.message;
  const phone = req.body.phone;
  const mail = {
    from: name,
    to: "admin@devlooper.me",
    subject: "Contact Form Submission - Portfolio Devlooper",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <p>Phone: ${phone}</p>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json(error);
    } else {
      res.json({ code: 200, status: "Message Sent" });
    }
  });
});

app.post("/subscribe", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.body.email) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Email is required' });
    }

    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const emailsCollection = db.collection('emails');

    const result = await emailsCollection.insertOne({ email: req.body.email });

    console.log('Email saved:', req.body.email);
    
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Subscription successful', insertedId: result.insertedId });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error subscribing:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is running! Click <a href="https://official-site-version-2-0-8tjp.vercel.app">here</a>');
});
```

And my Client side code is

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!email || email.indexOf('@') === -1) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://official-site-version-2-0.vercel.app/subscribe', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      // Handle response
      if (response.ok) {
        // If subscription is successful, call onValidated with success status
        onValidated('success', data.message);
        // Clear email field after successful subscription
        setEmail('');
      } else {
        // If subscription fails, call onValidated with error status
        onValidated('error', data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      // Handle network errors
      onValidated('error', 'Network error. Please try again later.');
    }
  };
```

Comment: What do you get if you add this to your `corsOption` config file: `mode: 'no-cors'`, like the error suggests you do?